# Using Command Links in Winforms .NET Core

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, custom-controls

I would like to add command links into my C# .NET Core Windows Forms app for Windows 10 21H2, but I haven't found any tutorials online.

I believe that this is a photo of a command link, but I'm not too sure. Can someone tell me how to add these to my app?

[image: command link]

I couldn't find any controls like this in the VS toolbox.

Comment: Windows Forms was created almost a decade before command links. Command Links aren't toasts anyway. The only way to use command links in Windows Forms is through Win32 API wrappers. There are several similar questions and the answer always involves wrappers. Way back when, there was a `Windows 7 Samples` repo on Codeplex that showed how to use those APIs and provided some wrappers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Custom Control, derived from Button, where the [BS_COMMANDLINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-styles) Style is added in the CreateParams property override.
This turns the standard Button Control in a CommandLink Button.
The `Text` Property value of the Control is shown to the right of the arrow, while the custom `LinkNote` Property provides the description that is shown right below the text, with a smaller Font.
When you set the `LinkNote` value, the [BCM_SETNOTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bcm-setnote) message is sent to the native Button. This sets the associated Note, at design-time or run-time.

The custom ControlDesigner is used to remove properties that are not needed / used when this style is set, or properties, as `FlatStyle` (which needs to be set to `FlatStyle.System`), that cannot be changed.
Unfortunately, this Designer works only in .NET Framework, to make it work in .NET 5+, you need to install the [Microsoft.WinForms.Designer.SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WinForms.Designer.SDK) package.
Open up the Package Manager Console and paste:

```
NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.WinForms.Designer.SDK -Version 1.1.0-prerelease-preview3.22076.5
```

This package is hard to find otherwise.
If you don't care about the Designer's features, just remove it

```
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
#if NET5_0_OR_GREATER
    using Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Designers;
#else
    using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
#endif

[ToolboxItem(true)]
[Designer(typeof(CommandLinkDesigner))]
public class CommandLink : Button {
    private const int BCM_SETNOTE = 0x1609;
    private string m_LinkNote = string.Empty;

    public CommandLink() {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.UseTextForAccessibility, true);
        FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
    }

    [DefaultValue(FlatStyle.System)]
    public new FlatStyle FlatStyle {
        get { return base.FlatStyle; }
        set { base.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System; }
    }

    public string LinkNote {
        get => m_LinkNote;
        set {
            if (value != m_LinkNote) {
                m_LinkNote = value;
                SendMessage(this.Handle, BCM_SETNOTE, 0, m_LinkNote);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style |= (0 | 0x0E); // Set BS_COMMANDLINK 
            return cp;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, string lParam);

    public class CommandLinkDesigner : ControlDesigner {
        private readonly string[] RemovedProperties = new[] {
            "AllowDrop", "AutoEllipsis", "AutoSize", "AutoSizeMode",
            "BackColor", "BackgroundImage", "BackgroundImageLayout",
            "Cursor", "FlatAppearance", "FlatStyle",
            "ForeColor", "Image", "ImageAlign", "ImageImdex", "ImageKey",
            "ImageList", "TextAlign", "TextImageRelation"
        };

        public CommandLinkDesigner() { }

        protected override void PreFilterProperties(IDictionary properties)
        {
            foreach (string prop in RemovedProperties) {
                properties.Remove(prop);
            }
            base.PreFilterProperties(properties);
        }
    }
}
```